# ERROR: el operador no existe: numeric = character varying

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I call to the next query by:

```
resultObject = em.createNativeQuery(sql)
    .setParameter(1, codEntidad)
    .setParameter(2, nroLote)
    .getResultList()
    ;
```

(`codEntidad`, `nroLote` are Integer) and then gives the next error:

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: el
>   operador no existe: numeric = character varying
>   Hint: Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los
>   argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de
>   tipos.
>   Position: 4539
>   Error Code: 0

But when I copy the result query and replace "?" with numbers and execute the query in pgAdim, it works correctly.

```
select c.nro_ci, c.nombre_completo, c.nro_operacion, c.moneda, c.nro_lote, 
   c.faja_inform, c.cod_entidad, sum(c.saldo_operacion) saldo_operacion, 
   sum(c.mto_capital) mto_capital, sum(c.val_int_adelantado) 
   val_int_adelantado, sum(c.int_dia_pago) int_dia_pago, 
   sum(c.monto_a_pagar) monto_a_pagar
 from (SELECT p.nro_documento nro_ci, p.nom_completo nombre_completo,
   c.operacion nro_operacion, s.nro_solicitud, s.cod_moneda moneda,
   sc.nro_cuota, sc.mto_capital saldo_operacion, sc.fec_vto_habil 
   fec_vencimiento, next_work_day3( CASE
                    WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' THEN
                        last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                    ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') END) fec_pago,
   case
   when sc.fec_vto_habil > next_work_day3( CASE WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' THEN last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                                            ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                           END)
   then 0
   else next_work_day3( CASE
                        WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' THEN
                            last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                        ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                       END) - to_date(to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
   end dias_interes, sc.mto_capital, sc.val_int_adelantado,
   case
   when sc.fec_vto_habil > next_work_day3( CASE WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' THEN last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                                            ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                            END) 
   then round((sc.mto_capital * 0 * 21) / 36500)
   else round((sc.mto_capital * (next_work_day3(CASE WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' THEN last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                                                ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                                END) - to_date(to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')) * 21) / 36500)
   end int_dia_pago,
   case
   when sc.fec_vto_habil > next_work_day3( CASE WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' THEN last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                                            ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                           END)
   then (sc.mto_capital - sc.val_int_adelantado) - round((sc.mto_capital * 0 
   * 21) / 36500)
   else
      (sc.mto_capital - sc.val_int_adelantado) - round((sc.mto_capital * 
        (next_work_day3( CASE WHEN to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 'MM') = '02' 
   THEN last_day(sc.fec_vto_habil)
                         ELSE to_date('30/'||to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 
   'MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                         END) - to_date(to_char(sc.fec_vto_habil, 
   'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')) * 21) / 36500)
   end monto_a_pagar, c.faja faja_inform, s.fec_insercion, c.nro_lote, c.cod_entidad
   FROM pr_solicitudes s, pr_sol_cuotas  sc, mi_com_cartera c, ba_personas p
   WHERE s.nro_solicitud  = c.nro_solicitud AND p.cod_persona = s.cod_persona
   AND sc.nro_solicitud = s.nro_solicitud AND sc.nro_cuota     <> 0) c 
  where c.cod_entidad = ?-->@COD_ENTIDAD and c.nro_lote    = ?-->@NRO_LOTE.
  group by c.nro_ci, c.nombre_completo, c.nro_operacion, c.moneda, c.nro_lote, c.faja_inform, c.cod_entidad order by 3;
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what is going on and what you are sharing in your example.  I had to use Google translate to understand your question.  I see several other examples of this issue.  Essentially, it seems that your key is expecting an Integer and you are passing a String or vis versa. You may need to convert them to match what the query is expecting.

Comment: "createNativeQuery" does NOT take in JDBC style parameters (`?`). It takes in numbered parameters (`?1`, `?2`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that "codEntidad, nroLote are Integer".
Make sure, that none of them is `NULL`, as JPA tend to misconvert `NULL` values.

Or add `CAST` to the parameters, something like this:

```
 WHERE c.cod_entidad = CAST(? AS integer) AND c.nro_lote = CAST(? AS integer)
```

Cannot use PostgreSQL's `::` operator for this, as in JPA the colon `:` marks the beginning of a parameter name.